# DateDiff gives A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, sql-order-by, datediff

I want to edit a query but I'm stuck. I want to order by a date (originally '2012-12-28') but i read it must be converted to unix timestamp to do that.
I don't know if i am doing it wrong so please help me!
The weird thing is when i execute the DATEDIFF alone there is no problem. But when i put it in the query there is.

Could anyone please help me?
This is the query. Simplified off course.

`"SELECT TOP 6 * FROM jd_lighthouses WHERE locations_aanvang != '' ORDER BY DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', '2012-12-28 00:00:00 +1:00') DESC";`

The error i get is:

`A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list position 1`

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Bram

> After comments here is the real code:
>
> `"SELECT TOP 6 * FROM jd_lighthouses WHERE locations_aanvang != '' ORDER BY DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', locations_aanvang+' 00:00:00 +1:00') DESC"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically you can do

```
ORDER BY (SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', '2012-12-28 00:00:00 +1:00')) DESC
```

This is utterly pointless and is optimised out though (no sort occurs).

The value of `DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', '2012-12-28 00:00:00 +1:00')` will be the same for all the rows so is of no use in an `ORDER BY`

Did you mean to reference a column rather than use hardcoded dates?

```
ORDER  BY DATEDIFF(s, some_column, '2012-12-28 00:00:00 +1:00') DESC
```

Comment: the actual code is
`"SELECT TOP 6 * FROM jd_lighthouses WHERE locations_aanvang != '' ORDER BY DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', locations_aanvang+' 00:00:00 +1:00') DESC";`
So i think i wrote my explanation wrong sorry!

Comment: @BramHammer - That doesn't give the error you state in the question.

Comment: nope i removed the CONVERT. my bad, was experimenting.
The error is now
`[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: So ask a new question about that as that is completely different from the question you asked.